# How to apply tzdata-java update after installing package

Tags: centos, java, daylight-saving

Updated the following packages via YUM on the system (CentOS 5 64bit)

```
tzdata-2012j-2.el5
tzdata-java-2012j-2.el5
```

The system package was applied correctly but the Java does not appear to be working - any Java application is logging data as an hour ahead of system time and any date/time conversions/actions produce a one hour offset. The offset is caused by out of date information about DST rollover (the servers are in Chile - the country is not kicking DST off until April 27th) which is supposed to be provided by the tzdata package. Again the OS is fine, it did not rollover on the 10th of March (original end of DST date) but the Java apps did even though updated tzdata-java was installed.

Is there something else that must be done to apply the package to the system?